Error: Route.post() requires a callback functions but got a [object Undefined] not working. \server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:216
there are several issues with the same theme, but I could not solve my problem.
`C:\Users\decokche\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:216
throw  Error(msg);
^
Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
at Route. [as post] (C:\Users\decokche\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:216:16)
at proto. [as post] (C:\Users\decokche\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:521:19)
at Object. (C:\Users\decokche\server\routes\User.js:28:8)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1246:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1300:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1127:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:112:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\decokche\server\index.js:4:20)
Node.js v19.5.0
`
index.js
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

const userRoutes = require("./routes/User")
const profileRoutes = require("./routes/Profile")
const paymentRoutes = require("./routes/Payments")
const courseRoutes = require("./routes/Course")

const database = require("./config/database")
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
const cors = require("cors")
const { cloudinaryConnect } = require("./config/cloudinary")
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload")
const dotenv = require("dotenv")

dotenv.config()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000

//database connect
database.connect()

//middleware (cookie parser addon kar rahe hai)
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
)
//file added middleware
app.use(
  fileUpload({
    useTempFiles: true,
    tempFileDir: "/tmp",
  })
)

//cloudinary connection
cloudinaryConnect()

//routes
app.use("/api/v1/auth", userRoutes)
app.use("/api/v1/profile", profileRoutes)
app.use("/api/v1/course", courseRoutes)
app.use("/api.v1/payment", paymentRoutes)

//def routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.json({
    // return res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    message: "Your server is up and running...",
  })
})

//activate the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("App is runnning at ${PORT}")
})

//delete kar denge kaam nhi ayega tab
// app.post("/route", (req, res) => {
//   // Your code to handle the POST request and generate a response
// })


User.js
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()

const {
  login,
  signUp,
  sendOTP,
  changePassword,
} = require("../controllers/Auth")

const {
  resetPasswordToken,
  resetPassword,
} = require("../controllers/ResetPassword")

const { auth } = require("../middlewares/auth")

//Routes for Login, Signup and Authentiation

// ****************************************************************
//                    Authentication routes
// ****************************************************************

//Route for user login
router.post("/login", login)

//Routes for user signup
router.post("/signup", signUp)

//Route for sending OTP to the users email
router.post("/sendotp", sendOTP)

//Route for Changing the password
router.post("/changepassword", auth, changePassword)

// ****************************************************************
//                   Reset Password
//  ****************************************************************

//Route for generating a reset password token
router.post("/reset-password-token", resetPasswordToken)

//Route for resetting user's password after verification
router.post("/reset-password", resetPassword)

// Export the router for use in the main application
module.exports = router



Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
